# converting strange timestamp from json to normal data time

Tags: json, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm getting some very odd looking timestamps from netflix's video API, they look like this ;

```
527637852762
```

I assume its a timestamp as in the json it looks like this,

```
"time": 527780548207
```

How can I convert this ? it should equate to around some day in September 2017.

So far I've tired dividing by 100, 1000 and no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe seconds since 01.01.1970 ?

Comment: What api method you using? And why this "time" property in this case?

Comment: Assuming it's a unix timestamp: if `527780548207` is the number of **seconds** since unix epoch, then it's equivalent to year 18694! If it's the number of **milliseconds** though, it's equivalent to year 1986. Timestamps from September 2017 will have values greater than 1504224000000 (milliseconds), and your value is much lower than that. There's no documentation for this API explaining what this value actually means?

Comment: I figured it out, its a 2001 timestamp. Seconds since 2001. So take that figure / 1000 and that converts correctly :) 
https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata

Answer (score 0):

Seconds since 1.1.1970?

It is a common [unix time stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 0):

**Referring to the Netflix API documentation they say:**

> For times since the epoch both seconds and milliseconds are supported because both are in common use and it helps to avoid confusion when copy and pasting from another source.

[image]

[Milliseconds Timestamp to Date](https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, its a 2001 timestamp. Seconds since 2001. So take that figure / 1000 and that converts correctly :)

epochconverter.com/coredata